# Page load time is more than a minute Mysql and Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have page load time issue in my project.
I have nearly 30000 records in my table and performing the search functionality on that table, Code is working fine but page loading time is very high (more than a minute). After fetching the result, I have done pagination in ajax, Ajax request also taking too much of time (more than minute) Below is my code please give any suggestion to overcome the problem.

```
 public function get_data($info,$limit,$offset=0){
    if(!is_array($info) && count($info)<1) return false;
    try{
        $orderbyString = "";
        $likestr = "";$or='';$plus='';
        if(isset($info['skill'])){
            foreach($info['skill'] as $key => $val){
                if($key!=0){$or=' OR ';$plus=' + ';}
                $orderbyString .=" ".$plus."  (( CHAR_LENGTH(r.resume) - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE ( r.resume, '".strtolower($val)."', '') ) ) / CHAR_LENGTH('".strtolower($val)."')) ";
            }
            $wholeString="ROUND ( ".$orderbyString." ) AS res_count ";
        }
        $this->db->select('r.resume_id, r.jobseeker_id, r.qualification, r.firstname, r.lastname, r.skills as skill_title, r.jobtitle, r.resume_date as last_updated_date, r.jobtype, r.location as city, r.country as state, r.workstatus, r.salary, r.experience, '.$wholeString.' ');
        $this->db->from('jp_resumes as r');
        $this->db->where('r.resume_status','1');

        if(isset($info['time_period']) && $info['time_period']!=='' && count($info['time_period'])>0 ){
            $date = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $info['time_period'][0]);
            $start_d=date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
            $dates = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $info['time_period'][1]);
            $end_d=date_format($dates, 'Y-m-d');
            $arr_two=array('r.resume_date >= '=>$start_d,'r.resume_date <= '=>$end_d);
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->where($arr_two);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['skill'])){
            //print_r($info['skill']);exit;
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['skill'] as $key => $val){
                $arr_two=array('r.skills'=>$val,'r.jobtitle'=>$val,'r.resume'=>$val);   
                $this->db->or_like($arr_two);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['work']) && is_array($info['work']) && count($info['work'])>0 ){
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['work'] as $key => $val){
                $arr_two=array('r.workstatus'=>$val);    
                $this->db->or_like($arr_two);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['jobtype']) && $info['jobtype']!=='' && count($info['jobtype'])>0 && $info['jobtype'][0] !== ''){
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['jobtype'] as $key => $val){
                $arr_two=array('r.jobtype'=>$val,'r.emp_type'=>$val);  
                $this->db->or_like($arr_two);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['state']) && count($info['state'])>0 && $info['state']!=''){
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['state'] as $key=>$val){
                $arr_one=array('r.country'=>$val);
                $this->db->or_like($arr_one);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        $this->db->order_by('res_count','desc');
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query === false){
            log_message('debug',__FUNCTION__." -> ".mysql_error());
        }else{
            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
                return $query->result();
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        log_message('error',$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using like operator, Its taking too much of time to execute. I update my code from like operator to Match(column_name) Against(value) and its works fine, now the page loading time is less than 5 seconds

Here is updated code

```
    public function get_resumes_comma($info,$limit,$offset=0){

    if(!is_array($info) && count($info)<1) return false;
    try{
        $orderbyString = "";
        $likestr = "";$or='';$plus='';
        $this->db->select('r.resume_id, r.jobseeker_id, r.qualification, r.firstname, r.lastname, r.skills as skill_title, r.jobtitle, r.resume_date as last_updated_date, r.jobtype, r.location as city, r.country as state, r.workstatus, r.salary, r.experience');
        $this->db->from('jp_resumes as r');
        $this->db->where('r.resume_status','1');

        if(isset($info['time_period']) && $info['time_period']!=='' && count($info['time_period'])>0 ){
            $date = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $info['time_period'][0]);
            $start_d=date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
            $dates = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $info['time_period'][1]);
            $end_d=date_format($dates, 'Y-m-d');
            $arr_two=array('r.resume_date >= '=>$start_d,'r.resume_date <= '=>$end_d);
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->where($arr_two);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['skill'])){
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['skill'] as $key => $val){
                $this->db->or_where('MATCH (resume) AGAINST ("'.$val.'")', NULL, FALSE );
                $this->db->or_where('MATCH (skills) AGAINST ("'.$val.'")', NULL, FALSE );
                $this->db->or_where('MATCH (jobtitle) AGAINST ("'.$val.'")', NULL, FALSE );
                //$this->db->or_like($arr_two);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['work']) && is_array($info['work']) && count($info['work'])>0 ){
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['work'] as $key => $val){
                $arr_two=array('r.workstatus'=>$val);    
                $this->db->or_like($arr_two);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['jobtype']) && $info['jobtype']!=='' && count($info['jobtype'])>0 && $info['jobtype'][0] !== ''){
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['jobtype'] as $key => $val){
                $arr_two=array('r.jobtype'=>$val,'r.emp_type'=>$val);  
                $this->db->or_like($arr_two);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        if(isset($info['state']) && count($info['state'])>0 && $info['state']!=''){
            $this->db->group_start();
            foreach($info['state'] as $key=>$val){
                $arr_one=array('r.country'=>$val);
                $this->db->or_like($arr_one);
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query === false){
            log_message('debug',__FUNCTION__." -> ".mysql_error());
        }else{
            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
                return $query->result();
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        log_message('error',$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had performance issue in mysql and codeigniter and i finally found that DNS name lookup timeout was the problem.

I was using centos and in my /etc/resolv.conf (DNS servers confugurations) was some unaccessible IPs. MySQL server tried to lookup for the name using those IPs and timeout occured.

I added skip-name-resolve to /etc/my.cnf and restarted mysql service and performance problem fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But my problem is like operator is taking too much of time to execute, I change the query